# How to save multiple tables as images using kable and map?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create multiple tables from a single dataframe and save them as images. When I'm trying to save the tables using `save_kable` something goes wrong. This is proxy of my code:

```
table_list  %>%
  group_split(compound, .keep = FALSE) %>%
  setNames(unique(table_list$compound)) %>%
   map(~save_kable(file = paste0('output/final_plots/1. model performance/',
                            names(.),
                            'table_metrics.png'),
              width = 6, height = 4, 
              bs_theme = 'journal', 
              self_contained = T, 
              x = kbl(., booktabs = T, align = c('l','l', 'c')) %>%
   kable_styling() %>%
    add_header_above(c(' ' = 1,
                       ' ' = 1,
                       'Metrics' = 5))))
```

The idea is to create a single table per split and save it as a png. Any ideas what might be wrong?

This is my dataframe

```
structure(list(`Avg type` = c("hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", 
"hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", 
"hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", 
"hourly", "hourly", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", 
"daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", 
"daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", 
"daily"), Scenario = c("CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT", "CCTM EFmaps", "CCTM PFT", "GC EFmaps", 
"GC EFmaps LD", "GC PFT"), compound = c("ISOP", "ISOP", "ISOP", 
"ISOP", "ISOP", "MACR_MVK", "MACR_MVK", "MACR_MVK", "MACR_MVK", 
"MACR_MVK", "MTP", "MTP", "MTP", "MTP", "MTP", "O3", "O3", "O3", 
"O3", "O3", "ISOP", "ISOP", "ISOP", "ISOP", "ISOP", "MACR_MVK", 
"MACR_MVK", "MACR_MVK", "MACR_MVK", "MACR_MVK", "MTP", "MTP", 
"MTP", "MTP", "MTP", "O3", "O3", "O3", "O3", "O3"), `Pearson coeff.` = c(0.73, 
0.74, 0.76, 0.76, 0.88, 0.34, 0.43, 0.66, 0.66, 0.79, 0.46, 0.48, 
0.26, 0.19, 0.3, 0.52, 0.64, 0.64, 0.63, 0.65, 0.83, 0.83, 0.89, 
0.9, 0.94, 0.71, 0.79, 0.89, 0.89, 0.96, 0.45, 0.48, 0.31, 0.28, 
0.41, 0.14, 0.66, 0.61, 0.61, 0.63), `Mean bias` = c(4.81, 0.23, 
0.18, 0.18, -0.19, 0.45, -0.08, 0.36, 0.36, -0.03, 0.53, 0.32, 
-0.07, -0.09, -0.08, 1.63, 0.27, 5.12, 5.07, 4, 5.22, 0.25, 0.2, 
0.2, -0.2, 0.44, -0.09, 0.36, 0.36, -0.03, 0.58, 0.35, -0.07, 
-0.09, -0.08, 1.44, 0.58, 5.36, 5.32, 4.19), `Mean error` = c(4.82, 
0.33, 0.43, 0.43, 0.21, 0.54, 0.18, 0.43, 0.43, 0.15, 0.54, 0.34, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.09, 9.26, 7.14, 8.25, 8.22, 7.17, 5.22, 0.27, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.44, 0.12, 0.39, 0.39, 0.07, 0.58, 0.35, 0.09, 0.1, 
0.08, 6, 3.63, 6.57, 6.52, 5.39), RMSE = c(0.37, 0.03, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.01, 0.04, 0.02, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.51, 0.37, 0.43, 0.43, 0.37, 1.37, 0.07, 0.16, 0.16, 0.04, 
0.11, 0.05, 0.12, 0.12, 0.02, 0.13, 0.08, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 1.32, 
0.79, 1.37, 1.36, 1.14), `Scatter Index` = c(1.1, 0.07, 0.13, 
0.13, 0.04, 0.17, 0.08, 0.17, 0.17, 0.05, 0.31, 0.18, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 3.89, 0.21, 0.44, 0.44, 0.12, 
0.46, 0.21, 0.53, 0.53, 0.08, 1.03, 0.61, 0.16, 0.17, 0.15, 0.07, 
0.04, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `map` does not have access to names of the dataframe so using `names(.)` would not work. You can use `imap` which by default passes data and name.
- `group_split` + `setNames` can be combined together in one step if you use `split`.

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(kableExtra)

table_list  %>%
  split(.$compound) %>%
  imap(~
    save_kable(file = paste0('output/final_plots/1. model performance/',.y,
                                'table_metrics.png'),
                  bs_theme = 'journal', 
                  self_contained = T, 
                  x = kbl(.x, booktabs = T, align = c('l','l', 'c')) %>%
                    kable_styling() 
                   )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

We may also do this without `split`ting i.e. using `nest_by` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
table_list %>%
    nest_by(compound) %>% 
    mutate(filename = file.path('output/final_plots/1. model performance', 
          str_c(compound, 'table_metrics.png')),
     new = save_kable(file = filename, bs_theme = "journal", 
      self_contained = TRUE, x = kbl(data, booktabs = TRUE,
            align = c('l','l', 'c')) %>%
            kable_styling))
```

-output

[image]